# Started my first Dapp, I have a trouble of Greeter tutorial

Tags: go-ethereum, greeter, tutorials

I started my first Dapp through this tutorial (“https://ethereum.org/greeter#the-solc-compiler”).
But, there is a step (following image show ) I can’t understand, don't know what should I do:
[image]

I search on Google, and I found this is a difference of Eth GitHub wiki tutoring:

[image]

And, I executed "eth.getCompilers()" is show 
[image]

I stopped at this step.
What should I do make I can create my Greeter Dapp?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Geth? eth.getCompilers are gone after geth geth 1.6.0. https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/209

> Deprecate eth_compile family of methods

And there is a tool that will help you compiling and deploying contracts. Truffle does the job. And yesterday they had a very good webinar explaining basics of smart contract and how to use Truffle (48 min): https://youtu.be/OoAC_AB4w-o

> Learn about the sweetest way to develop for Ethereum. Beginners welcome!

Comment: Thank you very much. my geth's version is   1.7.3-stable-4bb3c89d; I want to know how to execute the code is the official tutorial about first image's detail.